# Arm and leg length of standard Young Tableux

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

Quick question. I am struggling to understand the definition of arm and leg length of a cell in a standard Young Tabluea. I am not sure just how to fill in the boxes. As an example I am considering $ \lambda = (9,6,6)$. Or $9+6+6=21$. If you want to illustrate with a smaller example that is fine. I understand the arm length is the number of boxes to the "right" and leg length is the numbers of boxes "below".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose our diagram is of a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)$. The arm length of the box in row $i$ and column $j$ is $\lambda_i-j$. The leg length of the same box is the arm length in the transpose. Without referring to the transpose a formula is
$$\#\{p>i:\lambda_p\geq j\}$$

Comment: So in my example with $\lambda=(9,6,6)$ The arm length of the third box on the second row or cell (3,2) is $6-3=3$?

Comment: @Anthony that is correct. It's more common to call that cell $(2,3)$ however, like rows and columns of a matrix instead of coordinates.